# How to get frame of accessoryView frame in tableview cell ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Is there any procedure to get frame of Accessory View Frame in UITableViewCell. I tried a constant variable but frame of TableViewCell got changed for iPad and iPhones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using custom accessory view set via the cell's `accessoryView` property, you can get its frame using this same property. However, if you use the default accessory set via `accessoryType`, there's no built-in way to get its frame, but only by iterating over the cell's subviews and finding it there, it should be of `UIButton` class.

I'd suggest using a custom accessory view and getting its frame using the documented methods which should be safer.

Comment: @SrijanKumar you are welcome ;) Please mark this answer as accepted if this solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried another strategy that worked for me to get the width of this standard accessory, subclassing the UITableViewCell :

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()       
        let AccessoryWidth=self.frame.width-self.contentView.frame.width
}
```